# Getting an ANR and not sure what to do

Tags: android, android-logcat

I noticed my app will get an ANR and will literally hang there until I force the app to close. I'm not doing anything really on the main thread. I am using a 3rd party Video player SDK and I believe it might be something to do with that. I get this in the logcat:

```
Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I was also able to get the traces.txt from the phone when it goes into the ANR state. I'm not sure what I am supposed to be looking for but this is the main thread in the traces.txt. Does anyone see anything wrong in this?

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4162ee40 self=0x4154f828
  | sysTid=974 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073942868
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=14100 stm=9716 core=0
  #00  pc 00021814  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #01  pc 0001064f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+98)
  #02  pc 00010879  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
  #03  pc 0006aa9d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
  #04  pc 0002034c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #05  pc 00050e6b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  #06  pc 000297e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #07  pc 00030ae8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #08  pc 0002e180  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #09  pc 00063751  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
  #10  pc 0006b713  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #11  pc 000297e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #12  pc 00030ae8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #13  pc 0002e180  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #14  pc 0006346d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  #15  pc 0004ca37  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #16  pc 0004d0f7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #17  pc 0004de1b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
  #18  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
  #19  pc 0000e41b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
  #20  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1247)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1412)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Share code where you are launching media player

Comment: in your onCreate copy paste this code.

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());

Comment: It will tell you where you are doing something wrong

Comment: checkout its not related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482883/why-android-treats-an-app-in-anr-when-it-is-in-the-looper-waiting?rq=1