# Android ANR In libc.so

Tags: android

I'm getting an ANR report, which is reproducible by the user on a device I don't have. However, I see no threading issues in my own code, only the following.

```
DALVIK THREADS (27):
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7682cf40 self=0xb4827800 
| sysTid=29689 nice=0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb6ff4bec
| state=S schedstat=( 194686184 170352917 762 ) utm=10 stm=9 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0xbe5fd000-0xbe5ff000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/29689/stack)
native: #00 pc 0003732c  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
native: #01 pc 000121bf  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+26)
native: #02 pc 000121cd  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+6)
native: #03 pc 00010f23  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+98)
native: #04 pc 0001114d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+92)
native: #05 pc 00084d91  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvi+22)
native: #06 pc 000b61e3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I would be grateful for any ideas on what this might be. Several threads also have this same stack trace, but nothing pointing to anything in my code.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482883/why-android-treats-an-app-in-anr-when-it-is-in-the-looper-waiting ?

Comment: can you copy your code ?

Comment: how many activities do you have in your app

Comment: Do you have any webView in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the ANR report, I finally found that another thread was hung. I believe the trace I posted is proper behavior. Un-blocking the other thread fixed this issue for the user.

Comment: Could you please share more details? I'm having the same ANR report and couldn't find a way to reproduce it.

Comment: Try and get a developer log from your user and see if some non-main threads are hung. Unfortunately, you have to get lucky enough for a user to help you if you aren't seeing the issue. :-(

Comment: Hi @Justin can you please provide what thread is waiting and what is your fix. It will give some idea how to approach this Bug in our cases. (approach needed to attack such bugs)